# MS Access: IIF query like "text*"

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

I am trying to create a query in my database to display data in a useful way. [image: whole code picture]

I have queried the enquiries logged by my company to find the email addresses and associate the product codes they have enquired by

[image: example data]

What I now want to do is condense this data into a more useful format. So have the email address and the last of each info column and then have the product codes in column that are checked if correct.

[image: codes picture]

Does anyone out there have any ideas on how to get my data displayed like that?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). That includes sample data. None of those can be copied and pasted to be used for testing when people are trying to find an answer for you.

Comment: Edit question to include code as formatted text and data as text tables.

Comment: Images show field names without space but your expression has field name with space. Use LIKE with * wildcard. Missing quote mark at end of text criteria. Don't need quote marks around numbers. `Final: IIf([ProductCode] LIKE "Final*", 1, 0)`

Comment: Thank you for your help.
I tried uploading with the code and tables formatted as it showed me on here but it kept coming up with error messages saying I hadn't formatted the code properly. I do apologize.

Comment: Thank you for the help. i just wanted to post in case anyone ever finds it on google. The eventual answer to get the data how i wanted it was a cross tab query.
I ended up using the cross tab to push the data into columns and then use nested Iif statements to sort out the bad data

Comment: IIf([ProductCode] Like "Komatsu*","Komatsu",IIf([Productcode] Like "FinalDrive*","FinalDrive",IIf([Productcode] Like "final","FinalDrive",IIf([Productcode] Like "FinalPart","FinalPart",IIf([Productcode] Like "final part","FinalPart",IIf([Productcode] Like "final repair","FinalRepair",IIf([Productcode] Like "Main Pump","Main Pump",IIf([Productcode] Like "Swing","Swing",IIf([Productcode] Like "Slew Ring","Slew Ring",IIf([Productcode] Like "Access Equipment","Access Equipment",IIf([Productcode] Like "FinalRepair","FinalRepair",IIf([Productcode] Like "Recoil*","Recoil","Other"))))))))))))